# Add a field to a query where the data comes from a subform

Tags: web, ms-access-2010

I need to filter a a table with parameters that are calculated on a non related table, but to do this in Access web I need to add the [Project_Id] to the task list.

To clarify further, the user answers some questions regarding the details of a project, which in turn will calculate in the background a group of parameters that are needed to sort a task list.

The problem is the task list is generic and not related to a project so before I can use the project related filter parameters I need to assign a project id to the task list or there is no relationship and no way of knowing what project parameters to use.

I tried to do this with a query but being a Web database I am unable to select the data from the form control.

Hopefully someone can help me find a solution, because I have exhausted Google and my own knowledge on the subject.  One last thing I am unable to use code thanks to security issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested I found away to assign the project id to the task list using data macros.

The data macro is assigned to a table that is related to the project and when updated edits the tasks list to add the current project id for each record in the table.

I still have some issues to work around, but in general it does what I need.